# Reload multiple iframes on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I got a problem, and have been searching for answers for ages.
I have some iframes, with different HTML5 banners that plays inside. But they all start simultaneously, so i need the reload the iframe upon cycling through the tabs

HTML looks like:

```
<div class="main" >
  <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="show" checked/>
  <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="show" />
  <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="show" />
  <input type="radio" id="tab-4" name="show" />
  <input type="radio" id="tab-5" name="show" />
  <input type="radio" id="tab-6" name="show" />
  <input type="radio" id="tab-7" name="show" />
  <div class="tab">
    <label for="tab-1">320x320</label>
    <label for="tab-2">300x250</label>
    <label for="tab-3">300x600</label>
    <label for="tab-4">320x160</label>
    <label for="tab-5">160x600</label>
    <label for="tab-6">930x600</label>
   <label for="tab-7">930x180</label>
  </div>
  <div class="content">

    <div class="content-dis">
     <div>
       <a href="http://n" target="_blank" class="the-click"></a>
         <iframe id="iframe" src="https://b" width="320px" height="320px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
      </a>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="content-dis">
     <div >
       <a href="http://n" target="_blank" class="the-click"></a>
       <iframe id="iframe" src="https://b" width="300px" height="250px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
   </div>
```

*EDIT It should be mentioned that the iframe content is located on a different domain.

Comment: Are the url's on a different domain?

Comment: @user1408786 Yes, they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the src to the iframe dynamically, it should load as soon as it gets it.

So, for example, if you add the src of the iFrame when you click the tab, it should then load only at that point.

You can either have an array in wich the key is the ID of the iframe and the value is the url value, or you can add the url as a meta-tag in the html itself, and then use it in your javascript code to populate the src tag of the iframe

here's a quick example to show you the basic idea:

```
$('#test').on('click', function (){
  $("iframe").each(function() {
    var attr;
    attr = $(this).attr('data-frame-src');
    if (typeof attr !== typeof void 0 && attr !== false) {
      $(this).attr('src', attr);
    }
  });  
});
```

https://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/wdQLqR?editors=1010

The src of the frame loads on click of the button.

At the moment, I am adding to all the iframe the src, but you can easily run the function with the frame id as a parameter and add only that iframe src

Comment: Thanks! Could you give an example?

Comment: yes, check my update answer

Comment: Are you sure this works cross domain?

Comment: if the domain works in the iframe (it is allowed by the origin) it should work. All you are doing basically is taking the src and adding it later on, nothing else. If you try to put google on the frame, you can't as it is not allowed by the origin (google) but if you are using an allowed domain it will totally work.

Comment: The content of the iFrame doesn't show upon using 'data-frame-src' yet, I've tried uploading the source to the same server, and it still doesn't work

Comment: does it work without my method? do you get any error in the console?

Comment: console says "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at webbannershowcase.html:85"

Comment: you need to include jquery to use my bit of code

Comment: I can't just <script> it in the HTML?

Comment: Yes you can, but jquery needs to be included anyway. You can downlod it or use a cdn

Comment: Hahaha, my mistake. Thank you very much!! It works now, you have a great day!

Comment: no problem, glad it works ;)